# How to display column value of a relationship with laravel backpack?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent-relationship, laravel-backpack

Cannot display another column from a relationship on Laravel 9 + Backpack

So, i have a table with invoices ...
[image]

I have a table with clients ...
[image]

I have defined in my Invoices model the following relationship

```
public function client_id()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Client::class, 'client_id', 'client_id');
    }
```

... and i have defined in my Clients model the following relationship

```
    public function invoice() {
        return $this->hasMany(Invoice::class, 'client_id');
    }
```

My problem is that I cannot seem to find how I can display the company name for the company that the invoice has been issued.

[image]

I have looked into the documentation https://backpackforlaravel.com/docs/5.x/crud-columns#relationship-pro but i cannot seem to make it work.

```
 CRUD::addColumn([
        // any type of relationship
        'name'         => 'client_id', // name of relationship method in the model
        'type'         => 'relationship',
        'label'        => 'Client name', // Table column heading
        // OPTIONAL
        'entity'    => 'client_id', // the method that defines the relationship in your Model
        'attribute' => 'client_company', // foreign key attribute that is shown to user
        'model'     => \App\Models\Client::class, // foreign key model
    ]);
```

I'm guessing i'm doing something wrong. Any chance I could have a snippet?

Thank you,
George

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, it should be:

```
public function client()
{
   return $this->belongsTo(Client::class, 'client_id', 'client_id');
}
```

Second:

```
CRUD::addColumn([
        // any type of relationship
        'name'         => 'client', // name of relationship method in the model
        'type'         => 'relationship',
        'label'        => 'Client name', // Table column heading
    ]);
```

Comment: Worked perfectly. Sorry to be a pain, but i have tried this before, only difference method name in Invoice model was client_id. That's still just the method name, it should not supposed to work? Thank you